# Network Username Change : old username required to access shared folders

Tags: windows, windows-10

The username of one of the computers that I use has been changed. To access its shared folder via my local network I have to use the old username. A while back I remember having the same exact problem with another computer, I fixed it by doing a modification to regedit but I can't find the article I used last time on Microsoft's help. I would like to be able to use the new username to access the shared folder. I am looking for some guidance on fixing this issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the obvious but why can't you just change the share permissions on the machine serving the folder? Probably the easiest / most correct approach.

Comment: You are probably right but I would like to keep the permissions the same if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. No need to make any edits to regedit. Run `netplwiz`, select the old username and change it to the new username in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Map" function in file explorer to map the shared folder, you will have the option to specify different credentials to map the shared folder. You can also do this with the "net use" command on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the new username does not work. I have to use the old one. The password is not an issue. For example, before my username was `olderusername` and I changed it to `newusername`, well now to access the file when asked for credential I have to use `oldusername` as the user name.

Comment: Credentials means both user and password. You can specify both when you re-map the shared folder.